# Add the same associative element to each row of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do I add to the end of each sub array?  Here is an example.

```
$products = array( 
 array( Code => 'TIR', 
  Description => 'Tires', 
  Price => 100 
 ),
 array( Code => 'OIL', 
  Description => 'Oil', 
  Price => 10 
 ),
 array( Code => 'SPK', 
  Description => 'Spark Plugs', 
  Price =>4 
 ) 
);
```

I want to add SKU=>1234 after Price in each array.  Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Loop across the array and use references to modify it:

```
foreach ($products as &$v) {
  $v['SKU'] = 1234;
}
```

Comment: One thing to be wary of when using this technique: don't try to re-use $v in a second loop (without first calling `unset($v)`), or you'll end up with some very confusing behavior -- you'll end up overwriting $products[2], in this example.  To protect against this, I'm in the habit of immediately `unset()`ting the reference immediately after the completion of the loop... just in case any code below ever decides it wants to use the same variable name.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($products as $k=>$v){
    $v['SKU']=1234;
    $products[$k]=$v;
}
print_r($products);
```

Comment: Or, you can replace the lines inside the loop with a single one: 
    `$products[$k]['SKU']=1234;`

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ( $products as &$arr )
    $arr['SKU'] = 1234;
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the array using a [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) (Note the ampersand before the `$val`):

```
foreach ( $products as &$val ){
    $val['SKU'] = 1234;
}
```

That way rather than `$val` being a copy of the array element, it is a reference to the value, so altering it alters the value held in `$products`.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, functional iteration can be used to append the new element to all rows to create a new array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/a2rj2))

```
$new = ['SKU' => 1234];
var_export(
    array_map(fn($row) => $row + $new, $products)
);
```

---

Or use functional iteration to modify by reference instead of returning the data. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/QiDM0)

```
$new = ['SKU' => 1234];
array_walk($products, fn(&$row) => $row += $new);
var_export($products);
```